# XML Without Record Element need to convert into Table using TSQL / SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

XML without record element need to convert to a table using T-SQL in SQL Server.

```
DECLARE @X XML = '<ROOT>
                      <RECORD>
                          <ID>1</ID>
                          <AppCode>Code 1</AppCode>
                          <ID>2</ID>
                          <AppCode>Code 2</AppCode>
                          <ID>3</ID>
                          <AppCode>Code 3</AppCode>
                          <ID>4</ID>
                          <AppCode>Code 4</AppCode>
                          <ID>5</ID>
                          <AppCode>Code 5</AppCode>
                      </RECORD>
                  </ROOT>'
```

I tried like this

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN items.item.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(300)') = 'ID' 
            THEN items.item.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(300)') 
    END AS ID,
    CASE WHEN items.item.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(300)') = 'AppCode' 
            THEN items.item.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(300)') 
    END AS AppCode
FROM 
    @X.nodes('/ROOT/record/*') AS items(item)
```

Result was not correct -

```
ID       AppCode
-----------------
1        NULL
NULL     Code 1
2        NULL
NULL     Code 2
```

I need a result like this::

```
ID    Appcode
---------------
1     Code 1
2     Code 2
3     Code 3
4     Code 4
5     Code 5
```

Comment: What is your question? You've given us your sample data and expect results, but haven't asked anything. Have you tried anything so far to get from your XML to your results? Please do show us your attempts.

Comment: Your XPath in the `.nodes()` call has a `/INPUT` In it - but the XML doesn't show any `<INPUT>` element - so this XPath will select nothing....

Comment: Sorry, Let me update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UPDATE 2: This will be the best approach

Try it out

```
WITH Numbers AS
(SELECT TOP(@X.value('count(//ID)','int')) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Nmbr FROM master..spt_values)   
SELECT Nmbr 
      ,@X.value('(//ID[sql:column("Nmbr")])[1]','int') AS ID
      ,@X.value('(//AppCode[sql:column("Nmbr")])[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS AppCode
      ,@X.value('(//SomeMore[sql:column("Nmbr")])[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS SomeMore
FROM Numbers;
```

The idea

- count the IDs and return a derived *tally table* with a running number (in this case 1,2,3,4,5). Then use this number to address the elements by their position.

### Two more approaches, just for fun :-)

This should work with many columns pretty fast:

```
DECLARE @X XML = '<ROOT>
                      <RECORD>
                          <ID>1</ID>
                          <AppCode>Code 1</AppCode>
                          <ID>2</ID>
                          <AppCode>Code 2</AppCode>
                          <ID>3</ID>
                          <AppCode>Code 3</AppCode>
                          <ID>4</ID>
                          <AppCode>Code 4</AppCode>
                          <ID>5</ID>
                          <AppCode>Code 5</AppCode>
                      </RECORD>
                  </ROOT>';
WITH allIDs AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Pos
          ,id.value('text()[1]','int') AS ID
    FROM @X.nodes('/ROOT/RECORD/ID') A(id)
)
SELECT ai.Pos
      ,ai.ID
      ,@X.value('/ROOT[1]/RECORD[1]/AppCode[sql:column("ai.Pos")][1]','nvarchar(max)') AS AppCode
      ,@X.value('/ROOT[1]/RECORD[1]/SomeMore[sql:column("ai.Pos")][1]','nvarchar(max)') AS SomeMore
FROM allIDs ai
ORDER BY ai.Pos;
```

The idea:

- Read the IDs and find their position
- Read the corresponding elements by using the ID's position via `sql:column()`

### UPDATE: One more approach using *conditional aggregation*

This should be faster:

```
WITH AllNodes AS
(
    SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))-1) / 3 AS RowGroup
          ,nd.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') AS NodeName
          ,nd.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS NodeValue
    FROM @X.nodes('/ROOT/RECORD/*') A(nd)
)
SELECT RowGroup
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN NodeName='ID' THEN NodeValue END) AS ID
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN NodeName='AppCode' THEN NodeValue END) AS AppCode
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN NodeName='SomeMore' THEN NodeValue END) AS SomeMore
FROm AllNodes
GROUP BY RowGroup
```

The idea

- We read all nodes as an EAV-structure. The `(ROW_NUMBER-1)/3` (integer division!) will return a group index we can use in `GROUP BY`. The rest is *old-fashioned PIVOT*.

**Warnings for both approaches**:

- This needs a structure without missing elements. If XML might include sections, where one of the *follower nodes* is missing, this won't work.
- The solution with `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))` did work for me in all cases I've used it. But it is worth to mention, that this *is not guaranteed* to return the correct position.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the format you are after:

```
ID    Appcode
---------------
1     Code 1
2     Code 2
```

This is how I would do it:

```
DECLARE @X XML = '
<ROOT>
    <RECORD>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <AppCode>Code 1</AppCode>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <AppCode>Code 2</AppCode>
    </RECORD>
</ROOT>';


SELECT V.ID,AppCode
FROM @X.nodes('/ROOT/RECORD') AS X(R)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(X.R.value('(./ID/text())[1]','int'),X.R.value('(./AppCode/text())[1]','varchar(10)')),
                        (X.R.value('(./ID/text())[2]','int'),X.R.value('(./AppCode/text())[2]','varchar(10)'))) V(ID,AppCode)
```

This, however, won't scale. So if you have an ID of 3, 4, it's not going to give you more rows.

Comment: Nice, But I have Five Columns. Can it work with it? Let me try.

Comment: I have 5 Fields and 20 Records as Result

Comment: With the new sample you should easily be able to expand this @ISB. If you don't understand the above then ask, it's you who needs to support it. How it's getting each line should be quite apparent though.

Comment: Below gives result like separate table. Can you help how I combine these in single table

 SELECT T.c.value('(.)', 'nvarchar(MAX)') AS ID  FROM   @x.nodes('/ROOT/RECORD/ID') T(c) 
  SELECT T.c.value('(.)', 'nvarchar(MAX)') AS ID  FROM   @x.nodes('/ROOT/RECORD/AppCode') T(c)

Comment: That doesn't look anything like the SQL I wrote @ISB. Have a look at mine again, specially the `VALUES` clause. Notice that each row has an incrementing value for the singleton?

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify your XML format and use query as following to get result

```
DECLARE @X XML = '<ROOT>
                  <RECORD>
                      <ID>1</ID>
                      <AppCode>Code 1</AppCode>
                  </RECORD>
                  <RECORD>                      
                      <ID>2</ID>
                      <AppCode>Code 2</AppCode>
                  </RECORD>
                  <RECORD>
                      <ID>3</ID>
                      <AppCode>Code 3</AppCode>
                  </RECORD>
                  <RECORD>
                      <ID>4</ID>
                      <AppCode>Code 4</AppCode>
                  </RECORD>
                  <RECORD>
                      <ID>5</ID>
                      <AppCode>Code 5</AppCode>
                  </RECORD>
              </ROOT>'


DECLARE @doc int
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @doc OUTPUT, @X

SELECT ID, AppCode
FROM OPENXML(@doc,'/ROOT/RECORD',2)
WITH (
ID int,
AppCode varchar(10)
)
```

The output will like

```
ID  AppCode
1   Code 1
2   Code 2
3   Code 3
4   Code 4
5   Code 5
```

Comment: This is know. Problem is XML we are receiving from other system. Difficult to update / change XML

Comment: I think that modify XML will be much easier than T-SQL for unknown rows. If needed, I can help you write some t-sql code to update XML

Comment: Below gives result like separate table. Can you help how I combine these in single table 

SELECT T.c.value('(.)', 'nvarchar(MAX)') AS ID FROM @x.nodes('/ROOT/RECORD/ID') T(c) SELECT T.c.value('(.)', 'nvarchar(MAX)') AS ID FROM @x.nodes('/ROOT/RECORD/AppCode') T(c)

Comment: My t-sql is out put in one table

Comment: ;WITH CTE1 AS(
 SELECT T.c.value('(.)', 'nvarchar(MAX)') AS ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RR  FROM   @x.nodes('/ROOT/RECORD/ID') T(c)  
),
CTE2 AS (
SELECT T.c.value('(.)', 'nvarchar(MAX)') AS AppCode, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RR   FROM   @x.nodes('/ROOT/RECORD/AppCode') T(c) 
)
SELECT CTE1.ID, CTE2.AppCode
FROM CTE1 
JOIN CTE2 ON CTE1.RR = CTE2.RR